# Verb tense after stated expectation

Tags: grammar, verbs

In the following sentence:

> The newspaper expects its editors to check the facts.

What is the grammatical role of "to check"? Why can it not be replaced by "checking"? I thought they were both verbs. How does the verb "expects" modify what verb "check"?

Comment: *to check* is the verb in the infinitive clause "its editors to check the facts." That clause serves as the direct object of "expects." "Expects" and "check" do not modify each other; the latter is part of a complement to the former. *To check* and *checking* are both nonfinite verb forms. The verb *expect* licenses a to-infinitive or a relative clause, not a gerund. Other verbs license gerunds and not infinitives. (Try *see* in the template.) Alas, this is a matter of idiom, so there is no answer to why. Does that hurt or help?

Comment: @user105719 that helps so much I think it should be an answer